# d3 Pie chart not appending in angular

Tags: angular, d3.js

I am trying to create basic donut in angular 8.

**component**

```
 /* Pie Chart */
  donutWidth = 450;
  donutHeight = 450;
  donutMargin = 40;
  radius = Math.min(this.donutWidth, this.donutHeight) / 2 - this.donutMargin;
  svg = d3
    .select("#pie")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", this.donutWidth)
    .attr("height", this.donutHeight);

  ngOnInit() {
    this.svg;
  }
```

**html**

```
<div id="pie"></div>
```

I am wondering why this is not appending `svg` to div.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't working because the flow is wrong.  `this.svg` doesn't invoke the d3 call, it is invoked as soon as svg is defined. Since you have done `d3.select(#pie)` before the component has ever even been initialized, there is nothing for it to select. So instead do the call in `ngOnInit` like below:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.svg = d3
    .select("#pie")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", this.donutWidth)
    .attr("height", this.donutHeight);
  }
```

Hopefully this will solve your issue.